# Что выбрать между медленным bcrypt и быстрым SHA хеширования пароля?

Tags: криптография, sha, bcrypt

Для хеширования пароля можно использовать шустрый SHA-256 или SHA-512 с солью, что не рекомендуется, а можно использовать bcrypt, который работает очень медленно, что чревато лёгкой DoS-атакой на сервер.

На моей системе на 10 тысяч итераций SHA-512 уходит около 0,035 с, в случае bcrypt с минимально разрешённой сложностью - 9,8 с.

Как это решается на практике? Нет ли чего-то среднего по скорости между семейством SHA и bcrypt? Можно многократно хешировать SHA, но при этом упадёт криптостойкость.

Comment: Во-первых, поставить капчу — через неё злодеи устроить (D)DoS-атаку не смогут (скорее всего). Во-вторых, 9,8 с — это как-то запредельно много, в норме bcrypt отрабатывает где-то в пределах полсекунды, наверное вам нужно железо помощнее. А откуда вы взяли «минимально разрешённую сложность»?

Comment: @andreymal, если не ошибаюсь, капчу тоже можно атаковать, если не использовать предварительно сгенерированные картинки. И увы, она не всегда приемлема. 9,8 с уходит на 10 тысяч итераций, не на одну. Сложность - параметр в [функции](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php), путём перебора понял, что не может быть меньше четырёх.

Comment: О каких итерациях речь? Покажите какой-нибудь код, а то у меня начинает появляться подозрение, что вы используете bcrypt неправильно

Comment: @andreymal, [вот](https://pastebin.com/39ks5GR8) код, время замерял UNIX-овой `time`. Только не бейте сильно за PHP :)

Comment: @andreymal, в случае с SHA не использовал соль, но что-то подсказывает, что время не будет сильно отличаться.

Comment: Ну да, вы используете bcrypt неправильно, цикл нужно удалить. Алгоритм bcrypt изначально предусматривает в себе выполнение нескольких итераций. Число итераций равно 2 в степени выбранной сложности, то есть для сложности 4 будет 16 итераций, а для сложности 14 будет 16384 итерации. Сложность 12 (4096 итераций) на моём компьютере отрабатывает за 220 миллисекунд, так что уберите цикл, поставьте сложность 12 или больше — и этого достаточно.

Comment: @andreymal, я понимаю, что bcrypt сам по себе многократно хеширует, но при авторизации множества пользователей скорость однократного применения bcrypt будет иметь существенное значение.

Comment: Я очень сильно сомневаюсь, что у вас будет 432 тысячи авторизаций в день, поэтому скорость на самом деле не имеет никакого значения.

Comment: @andreymal, но опять же, что с DoS атакой в случае, когда капча неприемлема?

Comment: А почему капча неприемлема?

Comment: @andreymal, при авторизации через консоль, например. Или просто сервис для пожилых людей, которым не очень удобно вводить её каждый раз.

Comment: А зачем каждый раз? Достаточно требовать вводить капчу после трёх-пяти попыток входа например — это никак не затронет честные входы пожилых через консоль, но возможные проблемы от DoS-атак уменьшит.

Comment: @andreymal, понял Вас. Просто надеялся, что удастся обойтись без ещё одной таблицы учёта авторизаций и соответствующих запросов, но, видимо, нет. Спасибо за отклик!

Comment: Ну а вообще все эти bcryptы специально придумывают именно для того, чтобы **замедлить** расчёт хэшей, чтобы злодей не мог заняться подбором. Любое ускорение алгоритма автоматически означает снижение безопасности (возможно, несущественное, но всё-таки снижение). Если для вас забота о скорости важнее защиты от возможных утечек — просто ставьте сложность 10 или даже 8 и не парьтесь, например

Comment: Вместо монструозной «таблицы учёта авторизаций» лучше завести какое-нибудь простое и быстрое in-memory хранилище вроде Redis

Comment: @andreymal, да, но при этом снижается и производительность - хочется найти баланс. Нашёл [вопрос](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139721/estimate-the-time-to-crack-passwords-using-bcrypt), в ответе на который приводятся таблицы времени взлома bcrypt с разным cost factor. А насчёт Redis - я и позабыл о нём, спасибо!

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь за то, что влезаю в вашу беседу, но хотел бы спросить вас, @Андрей, каковы ваши предположения о злоумышленнике? Есть ли у него доступ к хешированному паролю, или нет? Он взаимодействует с вашей программой напрямую, или через сеть? Сколько одновременных сеансов авторизации он может запустить? Без этого обсуждение каким хешем пользоваться - сферично в вакууме. Одно дело, когда супостат может напрямую прочитать хеш и у него под рукой асики на пару терахешей в секунду. И совсем другое, когда супостат подбирает пароль через HTTP запросы.

Comment: @PakUula предположения о злоумышленнике — все сразу. Для защиты подбора в HTTP-запросах никакой хэш использовать вообще не требуется (достаточно капчи и/или лимита на число попыток), однако нельзя исключать и ситуацию, когда злоумышленник с асиками всё-таки получит доступ к хэшам (и кстати поэтому вместо bcrypt лучше взять какой-нибудь Argon2)

Comment: @andreymal Если супостат вооружен асиками, то тогда надо брать ethash с DAG размером больше 4 Гб или какую иную asic-resistant хэш функцию.

Comment: @PakUula Argon2 тоже вполне asic-resistant

Comment: Андрей, как вы видите из нашего обсуждения с @andreymal, начинать надо всегда с анализа возможностей оппонента. Если у него обычный компьютер, то даже SHA3 вам за глаза хватит. Разумеется, если у пользователей достаточно стойкие пароли. И совсем другое дело, если вы собираетесь противостоять кому-нибудь вроде  Bitmine с фермой асиков. Для них большинство локальных по памяти хэш функций слабоваты будут.

Comment: @PakUula не уверен, что вы имеете в виду под фразой «локальных по памяти», но Argon2 создавался именно для того чтобы нагружать память

Comment: PakUula, andreymal, спасибо. Для ethash, похоже, [уже есть ASIC](https://miningmoon.ru/product-category/algorithm/ethash/), для Argon2 [есть атаки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2#Атаки), хоть и не слишком существенные. Сейчас склоняюсь к использованию отрегулированного Argon2.